# How do I calculate the date in JavaScript three months prior to today?

Tags: javascript, date

I Am trying to form a date which is 3 months before the current date. I get the current month by the below code

```
var currentDate = new Date();
var currentMonth = currentDate.getMonth()+1;
```

Can you guys provide me the logic to calculate and form a date (an object of the `Date` data type) considering that when the month is January (1), 3 months before date would be OCtober (10)?

Answer (score 478, accepted):

```
var d = new Date();
d.setMonth(d.getMonth() - 3);
```

This works for January.  Run this snippet:

```js
var d = new Date("January 14, 2012");
console.log(d.toLocaleDateString());
d.setMonth(d.getMonth() - 3);
console.log(d.toLocaleDateString());
```

---

**There are some caveats...**

A month is a curious thing.  How do you define 1 month?  30 days?  Most people will say that one month ago means the same day of the month on the previous month <sup>[citation needed](https://xkcd.com/285/)</sup>.  But more than half the time, that is 31 days ago, not 30.  And if today is the 31st of the month (and it isn't August or Decemeber), that day of the month doesn't exist in the previous month.

Interestingly, Google agrees with JavaScript if you ask it [what day is one month before another day](https://www.google.com/search?q=one+month+before+March+31+1995):

[image: Google search result for 'one month before March 31st' shows 'March 3rd']

It also says that [one month is 30.4167 days long](https://www.google.com/search?q=one+month+in+days):
[image: Google search result for 'one month in days' shows '30.4167']

So, is one month before March 31st the same day as one month before March 28th, 3 days earlier?  This all depends on what you mean by "one month before".  Go have a conversation with your product owner.

If you want to do like momentjs does, and correct these last day of the month errors by moving to the last day of the month, you can do something like this:

```js
const d = new Date("March 31, 2019");
console.log(d.toLocaleDateString());
const month = d.getMonth();
d.setMonth(d.getMonth() - 1);
while (d.getMonth() === month) {
    d.setDate(d.getDate() - 1);
}
console.log(d.toLocaleDateString());
```

If your requirements are more complicated than that, use some math and write some code.  You are a developer!  You don't have to install a library!  You don't have to copy and paste from stackoverflow!  You can develop the code yourself to do precisely what you need!

Comment: var currentDate = new Date();
    var currentMonth = currentDate.getMonth() -12;
    var pastDate = new Date(2011, currentMonth, 01);
    alert(pastDate); this worked, checked with 12 months

Comment: This is a sick answer... Where i'm going to get 2012,0,15 from? Convert an existing month -1 ?

Comment: @AlexG - If you are new to JavaScript date parsing, then I can see how my quick example would be confusing. JavaScript expresses months as zero based, where January is zero. To avoid such confusion, especially since that has nothing to do with the question or my answer, I've updated my demo to get the date from a string, which should be more intuitive.

Comment: I know this is old but if the date is 31st March and you subtract one month using this method the result is the 2nd March.

https://jsfiddle.net/atamata/rvumf7dg/

Comment: @atamata - Yeah, that's weird, but predictable and expected.  31 days after the end of the previous month for March is March 31, but for February it's March 2.  If you want to count from the end of the month, you'll have to write some custom code for that.

Comment: Javascript doing javascript magic. But I get it and it makes sense: Date is a number internally, if you subtract a number from another number you get a third number, the third number is equally easy to format as a date as the first one, so this is simple mathmagics

Comment: This answer should not be accepted. `d.setMonth(d.getMonth() - 3)` will fail whenever the day for *d* doesn't exist in the month 3 months prior, e.g. 31 May - 3 months gives 31 Feb, which resolves to 2 or 3 March.  Also, `new Date("2012/01/14")` is fraught as that format is not supported by ECMA-262, so parsing is implementation dependent.

Comment: Well, simply put : 2nd snippet of @gilly3 answers the problem well..

that's the main answer actually, (when we mean _months_)

Answer (score 41):

I recommend using a library called Moment.js.

It is well tested, works cross browser and on server side(I am using it both in Angular and Node projects). It has great support for locale dates.

http://momentjs.com/

```
var threeMonthsAgo = moment().subtract(3, 'months');

console.log(threeMonthsAgo.format()); // 2015-10-13T09:37:35+02:00
```

`.format()` returns string representation of date formatted in [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. You can also use it with custom date format like this:`.format('dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a')`

Comment: Fast-forward to the future and you probably [don't want to use Moment.js anymore](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/).

Answer (score 24):

A "one liner" (on many line for easy read)) to be put directly into a variable:

```
var oneMonthAgo = new Date(
    new Date().getFullYear(),
    new Date().getMonth() - 1, 
    new Date().getDate()
);
```

Comment: nice! Not sure if it is applicable to every scenario, but seems to work fine enough.

Comment: This doesn't work if you are currently at, say, July 31st. The result will be July 1st instead of June 30th.

Answer (score 11):

This should handle addition/subtraction, just put a negative value in to subtract and a positive value to add. This also solves the month crossover problem.

```
function monthAdd(date, month) {
    var temp = date;
    temp = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1);
    temp.setMonth(temp.getMonth() + (month + 1));
    temp.setDate(temp.getDate() - 1); 

    if (date.getDate() < temp.getDate()) { 
        temp.setDate(date.getDate()); 
    }

    return temp;    
}
```

Answer (score 8):

To make things really simple you can use DateJS, a date library for JavaScript:

http://www.datejs.com/

Example code for you:

```
Date.today().add({ months: -1 });
```

Answer (score 8):

Do this

```
 let currentdate = new Date();
 let last3months = new Date(currentdate.setMonth(currentdate.getMonth()-3));
```

Javascript's `setMonth` method also takes care of the year. For instance, the above code will return `2020-01-29` if currentDate is set as `new Date("2020-01-29")`

Comment: The call to `currentdate.setMonth()` changes `currentdate`, so there is no need for assigning `last3months` to a new `Date` based on `currentdate`. Also, `currentdate` is no longer the 'current date'. Just a note to keep in mind using this solution. :)

Comment: Yep, it's call-by-reference and will change the currentdate variable

Comment: Just like user7394313's answer, this won't work if today is, say, July 31st, as it will return July 1st instead of June 30th.

Answer (score 7):

I like the simplicity of [gilly3's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7937257/4794), but users will probably be surprised that a month before March 31 is March 3. I chose to implement a version that sticks to the end of the month, so a month before March 28, 29, 30, and 31 will all be Feb 28 when it's not a leap year.

```js
function addMonths(date, months) {
  var result = new Date(date),
      expectedMonth = ((date.getMonth() + months) % 12 + 12) % 12;
  result.setMonth(result.getMonth() + months);
  if (result.getMonth() !== expectedMonth) {
    result.setDate(0);
  }
  return result;
}

var dt2004_05_31 = new Date("2004-05-31 0:00"),
    dt2001_05_31 = new Date("2001-05-31 0:00"),
    dt2001_03_31 = new Date("2001-03-31 0:00"),
    dt2001_02_28 = new Date("2001-02-28 0:00"),
    result = addMonths(dt2001_05_31, -2);
console.assert(dt2001_03_31.getTime() == result.getTime(), result.toDateString());

result = addMonths(dt2001_05_31, -3);
console.assert(dt2001_02_28.getTime() == result.getTime(), result.toDateString());

result = addMonths(dt2001_05_31, 36);
console.assert(dt2004_05_31.getTime() == result.getTime(), result.toDateString());

result = addMonths(dt2004_05_31, -38);
console.assert(dt2001_03_31.getTime() == result.getTime(), result.toDateString());

console.log('Done.');
```

Comment: "but users will probably be surprised that a month before March 31 is March 3" - I was indeed confused, but your solution works. Nice.

Answer (score 7):

For get date three monts prior to today :

```
let d = new Date(new Date().setMonth(new Date().getMonth() - 3))
console.log(d.toISOString().slice(0, 10))
// 2022-05-24 (today is 2022-08-24)
```

Answer (score 6):

If the `setMonth` method offered by gilly3 isn't what you're looking for, consider:

```
var someDate = new Date(); // add arguments as needed
someDate.setTime(someDate.getTime() - 3*28*24*60*60);
// assumes the definition of "one month" to be "four weeks".
```

Can be used for any amount of time, just set the right multiples.

Comment: I would go with gilly3's answer.  Yours assumes a fixed number of seconds per month.  JavaScript's lenient date arithmetic will keep the day correct.  THree months before September 28 should be July 28.

Comment: I wonder what JavaScript would calculate March 31st minus 1 month to be.

Comment: In that case you do get March 3 (for 2011) because that is what February 31st is in lenient mode.  But subtract _2 months_ and you will get January 31.  Under the 28-days per month model you would not.  As weak as the `Date` class is, and as much as Date.js is preferred, it at least models a lenient proleptic calendar that is good enough for casual use.

Comment: Shouldn't you multiple seconds to 1000 to correctly `setTime()`?

Answer (score 3):

```js
var d = new Date("2013/01/01");
console.log(d.toLocaleDateString());
d.setMonth(d.getMonth() + 18);
console.log(d.toLocaleDateString());
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the Smallest and easiest code.

```
   var minDate = new Date(); 
   minDate.setMonth(minDate.getMonth() - 3);
```

Declare variable which has current date.
then just by using setMonth inbuilt function we can get 3 month back date.

Comment: Why "minDate" ?

Comment: it's just a variable name

Answer (score 2):

There is an elegant answer already but I find that its hard to read so I made my own function. For my purposes I didn't need a negative result but it wouldn't be hard to modify.

```
    var subtractMonths = function (date1,date2) {
        if (date1-date2 <=0) {
            return 0;
        }
        var monthCount = 0;
        while (date1 > date2){
            monthCount++;
            date1.setMonth(date1.getMonth() -1);
        }
        return monthCount;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As I don't seem to see it already suggested....

```
const d = new Date();
const day = d.getDate();
const goBack = 3;
for (let i = 0; i < goBack; i++) d.setDate(0);
d.setDate(day);
```

This will give you the date of today's date 3 months ago as `.setDate(0)` sets the date to the last day of last month irrespective of how many days a month contains.  `day` is used to restore today's date value.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var todayDate = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10);
var d = new Date(todayDate);
d.setMonth(d.getMonth() -3);
console.log(todayDate)
console.log(d.toISOString().slice(0, 10));
```

Answer (score 1):

Since "Feb 31th" is auto converted to "March 3" or "March 2", as a month before "March 31th", which is quite counterintuitive, I decided to do it just like how I do it in my mind.
Similar to @Don Kirkby 's answer, I also revise the date with the last day of the target month.

```
function nMonthsAgo(date, n) {
  // get the target year, month, date
  const y = date.getFullYear() - Math.trunc(n / 12) 
  const m = date.getMonth() - n % 12
  let d = date.getDate()
  if (d > 27) {   // get a valid date
    const lastDateofMonth = new Date(y, m + 1, 0).getDate()
    d = Math.min(d, lastDateofMonth) 
  }
  return new Date(y, m, d) 
}

d = new Date('2022-03-31')
nMonthsAgo(d, 1).toLocaleDateString()
```

Finally, I love what @gilly3 said in his answer:

> If your requirements are more complicated than that, use some math and write some code. You are a developer! You don't have to install a library! You don't have to copy and paste from stackoverflow! You can develop the code yourself to do precisely what you need!

Answer (score 0):

d.setMonth changed local time in browser try

```
 const calcDate = (m) => {
    let date = new Date();
    let day = date.getDate();
    let month = date.getMonth() + 1;
    let year = date.getFullYear();
    let days = 0;

    if (m > 0) {
      for (let i = 1; i < m; i++) {
        month += 1;
        if (month > 12) {
          year += 1;
          month = 1;
        }
        days += new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
      }
    } else {
      for (let i = m; i < 0; i++) {
        month -= 1;
        if (month < 1) {
          year -= 1;
          month = 12;
        }
        days -= new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
      }
    }

    const newTime = date.getTime() + 3600 * 24 * 1000 * days;
    return new Date(newTime);
  };

calcDate(3)//+3 month
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
for (let monthOfYear = 0; monthOfYear < 12; monthOfYear++) {
  const maxDate = new Date();
  const minDate = new Date();
  const max = maxDate.setMonth(maxDate.getMonth() - (monthOfYear - 1), 0);
  const min = maxDate.setMonth(minDate.getMonth() - (monthOfYear), 1);

  console.log('max: ', new Date(max));
  console.log('min: ', new Date(min));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case I needed to substract 1 month to current date. The important part was the month number, so it doesn't care in which day of the current month you are at, I needed last month. This is my code:

```
var dateObj = new Date('2017-03-30 00:00:00'); //Create new date object
console.log(dateObj); // Thu Mar 30 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (ART)

dateObj.setDate(1); //Set first day of the month from current date
dateObj.setDate(-1); // Substract 1 day to the first day of the month

//Now, you are in the last month
console.log(dateObj); // Mon Feb 27 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (ART)
```

Substract 1 month to actual date it's not accurate, that's why in first place I set first day of the month (first day of any month always is first day) and in second place I substract 1 day, which always send you to last month.
Hope to help you dude.

```js
var dateObj = new Date('2017-03-30 00:00:00'); //Create new date object
console.log(dateObj); // Thu Mar 30 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (ART)

dateObj.setDate(1); //Set first day of the month from current date
dateObj.setDate(-1); // Substract 1 day to the first day of the month

//Now, you are in the last month
console.log(dateObj); // Mon Feb 27 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (ART)
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
   

 var date=document.getElementById("date");
    var d = new Date();
   document.write(d + "<br/>");
    d.setMonth(d.getMonth() - 6);
    document.write(d);

 if(d<date)
  document.write("lesser then 6 months");
else
  document.write("greater then 6 months");
```

Answer (score -1):

Pass a JS Date object and an integer of how many months you want to add/subtract. `monthsToAdd` can be positive or negative. Returns a JS date object.

If your `originalDateObject` is March 31, and you pass -1 as `monthsToAdd`, then your output date will be February 28.

If you pass a large number of months, say 36, it will handle the year adjustment properly as well.

```js
const addMonthsToDate = (originalDateObject, monthsToAdd) => {
  const originalDay = originalDateObject.getUTCDate();
  const originalMonth = originalDateObject.getUTCMonth();
  const originalYear = originalDateObject.getUTCFullYear();

  const monthDayCountMap = {
    "0": 31,
    "1": 28,
    "2": 31,
    "3": 30,
    "4": 31,
    "5": 30,
    "6": 31,
    "7": 31,
    "8": 30,
    "9": 31,
    "10": 30,
    "11": 31
  };

  let newMonth;
  if (newMonth > -1) {
    newMonth = (((originalMonth + monthsToAdd) % 12)).toString();
  } else {
    const delta = (monthsToAdd * -1) % 12;
    newMonth = originalMonth - delta < 0 ? (12+originalMonth) - delta : originalMonth - delta;
  }

  let newDay;

  if (originalDay > monthDayCountMap[newMonth]) {
    newDay = monthDayCountMap[newMonth].toString();
  } else {
    newDay = originalDay.toString();
  }

  newMonth = (+newMonth + 1).toString();

  if (newMonth.length === 1) {
    newMonth = '0' + newMonth;
  }

  if (newDay.length === 1) {
    newDay = '0' + newDay;
  }

  if (monthsToAdd <= 0) {
    monthsToAdd -= 11;
  }

  let newYear = (~~((originalMonth + monthsToAdd) / 12)) + originalYear;

  let newTime = originalDateObject.toISOString().slice(10, 24);

  const newDateISOString = `${newYear}-${newMonth}-${newDay}${newTime}`;

  return new Date(newDateISOString);
};
```

Answer (score -5):

```
Following code give me Just Previous Month From Current Month even the date is 31/30 of current date and last month is 30/29/28 days:

   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to display the date after changing the month.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {

var d = new Date("March 29, 2017"); // Please Try the result also for "March 31, 2017" Or "March 30, 2017"
var OneMonthBefore =new Date(d);

OneMonthBefore.setMonth(d.getMonth(),0);
if(OneMonthBefore.getDate() < d.getDate()  )
{
d.setMonth(d.getMonth(),0);
}else
{
d.setMonth(d.getMonth()-1);

}

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How does this answer differ from the 7 other, quite old answers, already present?

Answer (score -5):

```js
var d = new Date();
document.write(d + "<br/>");
d.setMonth(d.getMonth() - 6);
document.write(d);
```