# Set a variable class based on [date] value when MVC View loads?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

In my MVC5 webapp I am using [GridMVC](https://gridmvc.codeplex.com/) to render a button (styled hyperlink) in one of my grid columns to act as a verification button on assets. Basically when the button is clicked, it searches the DB based on its ID and sets the `[verified_date]` to the `DateTime.Now`. Below is the code for the column in question along with my script to update the `verification_date` value for the corresponding record:

```
@Html.Grid(Model).Columns(columns =>
    {
        // Other Columns
        columns.Add().Encoded(false).Sanitized(false).RenderValueAs(o => @<a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-sm noDecoration" onclick="verifyAsset(@o.Id)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> @*View*@</a>).SetWidth(15);
        // Other Columns
}).WithPaging(10).Sortable().Filterable().WithMultipleFilters();
```

**SCRIPT**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function verifyAsset(assetID) {
        var data = { asset_ID: assetID };
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "JSON",
            url: '@Url.Action("verifyAsset", "INV_Assets")',
            data: data,
            success: function (resp) {
                alert("Success! Asset " + resp.ID + " successfully verified on " + resp.VDate);
                location.reload(true);
            },
            error: function (resp) {
                alert("There was an error verifying this Asset...");
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

What I'd like to do on the View (during load) is: Set the class (`[btn-default]` above) based upon the date value of each record `[verified_date]` field which renders as (e.g. `2/24/2015 1:37:51 PM`). If the value for `[verified_date]` is older than 3 months from the current Date, I want the button (styled hyperlink) to have the `btn-default` class, else the `btn-success` class.

Then when the verification button is clicked, I also want to change the class for that particular record's verification button from `btn-default` to `btn-success`, after I update the `[verification_date]` value.

Does anyone have ideas for how to go about this?

---

**EDIT**:

Attempting Jason's idea, I'm having an issue with getting the individual `[verified_date]` value for comparison with the cutoff. This is what I currently have (result in comment):

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var cutoff = threeMonthsBack();

        $(".verifyBtn").each(function (index) {
            var date = new Date($(this).data("verified_date"));
            alert("Date: " + date + " || Cutoff: " + cutoff);
            // Date: Invalid Date || Cutoff: Tue Nov 25 2014 08:42:54 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)

            if (date < cutoff) {
                $(this).removeClass("btn-success").addClass("btn-default");
            }
            else {
                $(this).removeClass("btn-default").addClass("btn-success");
            }
        });

        $("a.btn-default").on("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).removeClass("btn-default").addClass("btn-success");
        });

        function threeMonthsBack() {
            var _date = new Date();
            _date.setMonth(_date.getMonth() - 3);
            return _date;
        }
    });
    }
</script>
```

What I need to do is set the `date` variable to be the `[verified_date]` for each of my grid records, then compare it for being greater or less than 3 months back from today's current date.

I set up one of my records to have a `[verified_date]` of 11/24/2014. This is the HTML that renders:

```
<td class="grid-cell" data-name="verified_date">11/24/2014 12:00:00 PM</td>
```

And this is the HTML for that same record's `verifyBtn`:

```
<td class="grid-cell" data-name>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm noDecoration verifyBtn btn-success" onclick="verifyAsset(8)">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok">...</span>
    </a>
</td>
```

How do I set the `date` variable to be the value contained in my `[verified_date]` of each row? If I'm understanding somewhat correctly, the above code for `date` var in my script is currently seeking a `data` value for `verified_date`, but the `verifyBtn` itself does not have this property?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with jQuery's **.ready()**, **.each()**, **.addClass()**, and **.removeClass()**. Here's the basic idea:

I don't know what your html markup looks like but let's suppose:

```
<a href="#" data-date="2/24/2015 1:37:51 PM" class="btn btn-default">A</a>
<a href="#" data-date="1/24/2015 1:37:51 PM" class="btn btn-default">B</a>
<a href="#" data-date="5/24/2015 1:37:51 PM" class="btn btn-default">C</a>
```

Now we use the `.ready()` for the document loaded event.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // use a more discriminating selector than "a"
    $("a").each(function(index) {
        var date = new Date($(this).data("date"));
        var cutoff = threeMonthsBack();
        if (date < cutoff) {
            $(this).removeClass("btn-success").addClass("btn-default");
        }
        else {
            $(this).removeClass("btn-default").addClass("btn-success");
        }
    });

    $("a.btn-default").on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).removeClass("btn-default").addClass("btn-success");
    });
});
```

This will only work if your grid is loaded via a standard page load. If you load this via AJAX you'll need to add this to the AJAX success handler.

If you want to wait for your verification from the server move that click handler into your verify success handler.

```
success: function(resp) {
    ...
    // you'll need to id or pass through verifyAsset()
    $(assetID).removeClass("btn-default").addClass("btn-success");
}
```

**Edit:**

With your edit we suppose the html is set up so your button and data are in separate cells of the same row.

```
<tr>
    <td class="grid-cell" data-name="verified_date">11/24/2014 12:00:00 PM</td>
    <td class="grid-cell" data-name>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm noDecoration verifyBtn btn-success" onclick="verifyAsset(8)">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok">...</span>
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

This is where jQuery's [traversal functions](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/) become handy. Since we assume the button and grid are on the same row we find the button then traverse up the DOM tree to find its parent `<tr>` then search back through the tr's children for the sibling data cell.

```
$(".verifyBtn").each(function (index) {
    var me = $(this);  // the button
    var parent = me.closest("tr");
    var sibling = parent.find("td[data-name='verified_date']:first");
    var datestr = sibling.html();
    // or just chain it all
    // var datestr = $(this).closest("tr").find("td[data-name='verified_date']:first").html();
    var date = new Date(datestr);
    var cutoff = threeMonthsBack();
    if (date < cutoff) {
        $(this).removeClass("btn-success").addClass("btn-default");
    }
    else {
        $(this).removeClass("btn-default").addClass("btn-success");
    }
});
```

Here's a simplistic example http://jsfiddle.net/1b50zx0t/2/

Comment: Instead of the "a" selector I added a class to the button (hyperlinks) of `.verifyBtn`. Do you have an actual way to do the comparison for the `threeMonthsBack()` from the `[verified_date]` value?

Comment: Get the current date which is milliseconds since the epoch. Then subtract 3 months worth of milliseconds for the cutoff date. Or you can just take [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7937233/how-do-i-calculate-the-date-in-javascript-three-months-prior-to-today).

Comment: After some testing I realized there is an issue on setting the value for the `date` variable used in the comparison. Please see EDIT above.