# Event Calendar-PHP (How to create blank cells after the last date of the month)

Tags: php

I am creating an event calendar following a tutorial. However, the problem I am facing is that I do not know how to create the necessary blank cells after the last day of the month. Here is the code:

calender.php

```
<?php

//These are required to connect to the database

DEFINE ('DB_USER', 'root');
DEFINE ('DB_PASSWORD', '');
DEFINE ('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
DEFINE ('DB_NAME', 'calender');

//This variable is used for displaying error
$error="Cannot connect";

//Connect to the database
$dbconnection=mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) or die($error);
mysqli_select_db($dbconnection,"calender") or die($error);

?>

 <html> 

 <head> 

 <script> 

//This function represents the previous button on the calender

function goPreviousMonth(month, year){ 
if (month == 1) { 
--year; 
month = 13; 

} 

--month
var monthstring=""+month+"";
var monthlength=monthstring.length;
if(monthlength<=1){
    monthstring="0"+monthstring;
 }

//This creates the URL to state the month and year.
document.location.href = "<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>?month="+monthstring+"&year="+year; 
} 

//This function represents the next button on the calender

function goNextMonth(month, year){ 
if (month == 12){ 
++year; 
month = 0; 
} 

++month
var monthstring=""+month+"";
var monthlength=monthstring.length;
if(monthlength<=1){
    monthstring="0"+monthstring;
}

//This creates the URL to state the month and year.
document.location.href = "<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>?month="+monthstring+"&year="+year; 
} 

</script> 

</head> 

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="calenderstyle.css">

<body> 

<?php 

//Check the URL to see if the user has passed a variable

//This is used to check if day has a passing variable 

if (isset ($_GET['day'])){ 

//If true, then get the day from the URL
$day = $_GET['day']; 
}else{ 
$day = date ("d");
} 

//The is used to check if month has a passing variable
if (isset ($_GET['month'])){ 

//If true, then get the month from the URL
 $month = $_GET['month']; 
 }else{ 
 $month = date ("n"); 
 } 

//The is used to check if month has a passing variable
if (isset ($_GET['year'])){ 
//If true, then get the year from the URL
 $year = $_GET['year']; 
 }else{ 
 $year = date ("Y"); 
 } 

 //The calender variables
 //This stores day, month and year variables within a timestamp
 $currentTimeStamp = strtotime("$year-$month-$day"); 

 //This gets the current month name 
 $monthName = date("F", $currentTimeStamp); 

 //This determines how many days there are in the current month 
 $numDays = date("t", $currentTimeStamp); 

 //This variable is used to count cells in the loop later
 $counter = 0; 
 ?> 

 <?php
 //This code must be below the date variable
 if(isset($_GET['add'])){
     $title=$_POST['txttitle'];
     $detail=$_POST['txtdetail'];
     $eventdate=$month."/".$day."/".$year;

     $sqlinsert="insert into booking (title,detail,event_date,date_added) values ('".$title."','".$detail."','".$eventdate."',now())";

     $resultinsert=mysqli_query($dbconnection,$sqlinsert);

     if($resultinsert){
         echo "Event was successfully added";
      }else{
         echo "Event was not added";
      }

 }
 ?>

 <table border='1'> 

    <tr> <td> <input class="previousbutton" type='button' value='<' name='previousbutton' onClick="goPreviousMonth (<?php echo $month.",".$year?>)"> </td> 
     <td colspan='5'> <span class="title"> <?php echo $monthName." ".$year; ?> </span> </td> 
     <td> <input class="nextbutton"  type='button' value='>' name='nextbutton' onClick="goNextMonth (<?php echo $month.",".$year?>)"> </td> 
    </tr> 

 <tr> 

    <td>Sun</td> 
    <td>Mon</td> 
    <td>Tue</td> 
    <td>Wed</td> 
    <td>Thu</td> 
    <td>Fri</td> 
    <td>Sat</td> 

 </tr> <?php echo "<tr>"; 

 //This is used to loop from 1 to the number of days in the month
 for ($i = 1; $i < $numDays+1; $i++, $counter++){

 //This is a timestamp for each day in the loop
 $timeStamp = strtotime ("$year-$month-$i"); 

//This checks if if it is the first day
if($i == 1){ 

    //This determines which day for the first date of the month
    $firstDay = date ("w", $timeStamp);

    //This loop is used to make a blank cell if it is not the first day
    for ($j = 0; $j < $firstDay; $j++, $counter++){ 

    //Blank space 
    echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>"; 
    } 
   } 

    //This checks to see if the day is on the last column. If so, a new row will be made.
    if($counter % 7 == 0 ){     
    echo "<tr></tr>"; 
 } 

$monthstring=$month;
$monthlength=strlen($monthstring);
$daystring=$i;
$daylength=strlen($daystring);

if($monthlength<=1){
$monthstring="0".$monthstring;  
}

if($daylength<=1){
    $daystring="0".$daystring;
}

$todaysDate=date("m/d/Y");
$dateToCompare=$monthstring. '/' . $daystring . '/' . $year;
echo "<td align='center' ";

if($todaysDate==$dateToCompare){
echo "class='today'";   
}else{

    $sqlCount="select * from booking where event_date='".$dateToCompare."'";
    $noOfEvent= mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($dbconnection,$sqlCount));
    if($noOfEvent>=1){
        echo "class='event'";
    }
 }

 echo "><a href='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?month=".$monthstring."&day=".$daystring."&year=".$year."&v=true'>".$i."</a></td>";
 } 

 echo "</tr>"; 
  ?> 

 </table> 

 <?php

 if(isset($_GET['v'])){
     echo "<a href='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?month=".$month."&day=".$day."&year=".$year."&v=true&f=true'>Add Event</a>";
     if(isset($_GET['f'])){
         include("eventform.php");
     }

     $sqlEvent="select * from booking where event_date='".$month."/".$day."/".$year."'";
     $resultEvents=mysqli_query($dbconnection,$sqlEvent);
     echo "<hr>";
     while($events=mysqli_fetch_array($resultEvents)){
     echo "Title : ".$events['title']."<br>"; 
     echo "Detail : ".$events['detail']."<br>";
     }
 }

 ?>

 </body> 

 </html>
```

calenderstyle.css

```
table {
position: absolute;
width: 700px;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -350px;
margin-top:-30px;
text-align: center; 
border-collapse: collapse;
font-size: 20px;
}

table tr td a {
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
width:100%;
padding: 20% 0;
}

td {
width: 100px;
height: 60px;
background-color: white;
}


a:link {
color: black;
}

a:visited {
color: black;
}

td:hover {
background-color: khaki;
}

.previousbutton{
width: 100px;
height: 60px;
border: none;
background-color: blue;
cursor: pointer;
font-size:20px;
}

.previousbutton:hover{
background-color: #7FFFD4;
}

.nextbutton{
width: 100px;
height: 60px;
border: none;
background-color: blue;
cursor: pointer;
font-size:20px;
}

.nextbutton:hover{
background-color: #7FFFD4;
}

.today {
background-color: yellow;
}

.event {
background-color: green;
}

tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(2){
background-color: green;
}

tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(1n){
background-color: #D3D3D3;
}

.title {
color:white;    
}
```

eventform.php

```
<form name='eventform' method='POST' action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>?month=<?php echo $month;?>&day=<?php echo $day;?>&year=<?php echo $year;?>&v=true&add=true">

<table width='400px'>
    <tr>
        <td width='150px'>Title</td>
        <td width='250px'><input type='text' name='txttitle'> </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td width='150px'>Detail</td>
        <td width='250px'> <textarea name='txtdetail'> </textarea> </td>
    </tr>

<tr>
    <td td colspan='2'align='center'> <input type='submit' name='btnadd' value='Add Event'> </td>
</tr>
</table>

</form>
```

So for example, if you look at the month October 2017, you can see that after 31st, there is a huge empty gap between the 31st and the end of the calendar.
If you look at November there is at least a 2 cell gap between the 30th and the end of the calendar, while for December 2017, there is a huge gap between the 31st and the end of the calendar.

Which is why I wanted to kindly ask if anybody knew how to fill in the empty gap with blank white cells (similar to what is shown before the first day of the month) but in this case, between the last day and the end of the calendar?

Comment: First a few hints: 1. Your document is missing a doctype 2. Welcome to 2017. `if (isset ($_GET['day'])){ $day = $_GET['day']; }else{ $day = date ("d"); }` => `$day = $_GET['day'] ?? date('d');` 3. `<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>` could be a security issue and should not be used. better use `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` 4. you're violating the IPO model! 5. just check if `$counter` is greather than `$numDays`. If this is true you're printing a cell at the moment that is not part of the current month.

Comment: BTW: `<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>` does nothing. You're missing an echo :)

Comment: you have a security issue in reason of not taking care of switching the context from serverside php to clientside html (XSS)

Comment: Thanks for attempting to help. Unfortunately, the solution did not work- number 5. I really am stuck with this one...

Comment: Please update your question with the latest version of your code. What did you try and what is not working? Show Code and result and what you want to achieve.

Comment: I tried using a basic if statement: if($counter>$numDays) { echo "<tr><tr>"}. or tried something like return ($counter>$numDays). Nothing seemed to work unfortunately. The code is all available (minus the code here) above. The calender works, but unfortunately the blank cells after the last date can't be created.

Comment: I will post you a solution tomorrow. Furthermore (if it's ok) I will show you how to improve your code in performance, structure and readability (it's a little bit hard to read ;)).

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind help. It is appreciated. And please, if you feel you can improve the code in anyway, then go ahead. I forgot to mention- in the code, that there are 2 databases used in the event calendar. You can find them in the code. Thank you again.

Comment: I didn't get it finished today. But I don't forget you. I will post it tomorrow or the day after! I hope you're not mad.

Comment: LOL. No problem my friend. Look forward to your solution

Answer (score 0):

First of all the solution to your question:

Just check if the actual day (the table cell that should printed for the actual day) is greater than the last day. The condition for this should look like this:

```
$actualDay > $amountOfDaysOfMonth + $firstday
```

For example: the amount of days for the month november is 30. This year (2017) it starts at the fourth day (wednesday). That means that it ends at thursday, the 30th. Your calender should look like that: the first three fields are empty. The next 30 are full and the next two cells are empty again. Your problem are the last two. The condition is: If the actual cell is greater than 30 + 3 (=33) it's behind the end of the month.

That's all.

```
if($i > $numDays + $firstday) { /* It's an empty cell! */ }
```

Or (like I changed it in the code below) you calculate the date of the cell and compare the month of the cell date with the month of the actual Date. That works too.

**Now (as pre-decided in the comments) some improvements on your code!**

Some Improvements (PHP Code):

1. First of all: If you code php and you are working on developement infrastructure you should set the proper debuging options. If you want you can use a real debugger (like [Xdebug](https://xdebug.org/)). But the minimum is to set the following:

   ```
   error_reporting(E_ALL);
   ini_set('display_errors', '1');
   ```

   With these settings you see all the errors that appear in your application on the directly on the screen.
2. `$error="Cannot connect";`: Why are you doing this? Just print the *real* error message and not your own. The message "Cannot connect" helps nothing to solve the issue. Just use the right functions ([mysqli_errno](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.errno.php) and [mysqli_error](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) or [mysqli_error_list](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error-list.php)) for that.
3. Now you're starting the html output. **But** later on you're writing php functions, have business logic, database querys. That violates the IPO model. IPO stands for Input-Processing-Output. What that means: first you get input and you check that input and so on. Second you do all the logic and stuff you want to do, but you don't print anything. The last step is to output your content. If you mix this up you can get problems. One very popular example is the "Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by ... on line X". That happens if you have output before calling the [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function.
4. `<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>` This is doing **nothing**. You have to echo the value of `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`. If you don't do this: nothing's happening. Correct (for the moment, see 5. and 6.): `<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>`
5. Using `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` can lead to [some security issues](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/83619/security-issue-with-form-action-serverphp-self). Better use `$_SERVER['SCRIPTNAME']`.
6. Instead of `<?php echo ...; ?>` just use the template language of php: `<?=...?>`. That means the same but is a way shorter.
7. Take a look at the following code:

   ```
   if (isset ($_GET['day'])){
       //If true, then get the day from the URL
       $day = $_GET['day'];
   }else{
       $day = date ("d");
   }
   ```

   This is the way you did it before PHP7. Now you write:

   ```
   $day = $_GET['day'] ?? date('d');
   ```

   That means exactly the same!
8. The whole code for time and date calculations can be done a littl bit more straightforward if you use the `\DateTime` Class.

Some Improvements (HTML/JS):

1. Your html markup is missing a doctype!
2. A little bit of math can shorten your code:

   ```
   function goPreviousMonth(month, year){ 
       if (month == 1) { 
           --year; 
           month = 13; 
       } 
       --month
       var monthstring=""+month+"";
       var monthlength=monthstring.length;
       if(monthlength<=1){
           monthstring="0"+monthstring;
       }
       //This creates the URL to state the month and year.
       document.location.href = "<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>?month="+monthstring+"&year="+year; 
   }
   ```

   The same code with the power of "math" ;) :

   ```
   function goPreviousMonth(month, year){
       if(month == 1) year--;
       month = (month+10) % 12 + 1;
       month = ("0"+month).slice(-2);
       //This creates the URL to state the month and year.
       document.location.href = "<?=$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];?>?month="+month+"&year="+year; 
   }
   ```
3. instead of calculating your own dates... just take use of the `Date` object in javascript!

After all that changes your code could look something like this:

```
<?php

    // should be removed before uploading to production infrastructure!!
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');

    //These are required to connect to the database
    DEFINE ('DB_USER', 'root');
    DEFINE ('DB_PASSWORD', '');
    DEFINE ('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
    DEFINE ('DB_NAME', 'calender');

    //Check the URL to see if the user has passed a variable

    //This is used to check if day has a passing variable and if not to set a default value
    $day = $_GET['day'] ?? date('d');
    $month = $_GET['month'] ?? date('n');
    $year = $_GET['year'] ?? date('Y');

    //The calender variables
    //This stores day, month and year variables within a \DateTime class
    $currentDate = new DateTime("$year-$month-$day");
    $currentDate->setTime( 0, 0, 0 );

    //This gets the current month name 
    $monthName = $currentDate->format("F");

    //This determines how many days there are in the current month 
    $numDays = $currentDate->format("t");

    //This determines which day for the first date of the month
    $firstDayOfCurrentMonth = $currentDate->format("w");

    // used for adding events
    $successFullInsertedEvent;

    //Connect to the database
    $dbconnection=mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
    if(mysqli_connect_errno())
        die(mysqli_connect_error()); // normaly you should use some kind of error handler instead of just "kill" your script.
    mysqli_select_db($dbconnection,"calender") or die(mysqli_error($dbconnection));

    //This code must be below the date variable
    if(array_key_exists('add', $_GET)){
        $title=$_POST['txttitle'];
        $detail=$_POST['txtdetail'];

        $sqlinsert=sprintf(
            "INSERT INTO booking (title,detail,event_date,date_added) values ('%s','%s','%s',NOW())",
            mysqli_real_escape_string($dbconnection, $title),
            mysqli_real_escape_string($dbconnection, $detail),
            mysqli_real_escape_string($dbconnection, $currentDate->format('Y-m-d'))
        );

        $successFullInsertedEvent = mysqli_query($dbconnection, $sqlinsert);
    }

    // if you can use a template engine: do it. If you don't want to: ok no problem, let's use a helper function for the
    // content of a cell, so that the html code keeps clear:
    function getContentsOfCell($cellNo, $startingDate) {
        // $startingDate is within the current month. So lets create a date that corresponds to the cell number:
        // We set the day to the first of the month.
        // Now we add the cellNo
        // But wait... there can be some days before the first of the month, so lets substract these days
        $dateOfCell = new \DateTime($startingDate->format('Y-m-01'))->add('+'.($cellNo-$startingDate->format('w')).' days');
        $dateOfCell->setTime( 0, 0, 0 );
        if($dateOfCell->format('m') !== $startingDate->format('m')) {
            // the date of the cell and the date of the current month are not the same: before the month beginns or after the month ends
            return [
                'classList':[],
                'attributes':[],
                'content':'#'
            ];
        }
        // If we get here: The actual Cell is within the current month
        $dateToCompare = $dateOfCell->format('m/d/Y'); // format: mm-dd-YYYY
        $return = [
            'classList':[],
            'attributes'[
                'align="center"'
            ],
            'content':''
        ];
        $today = new DateTime('today');
        if((int)($today->diff($dateOfCell))->format('%R%a') === 0) {
            $result['classList'][] = 'today';
        } else {
            $sqlCount="SELECT * FROM booking WHERE event_date='".$dateToCompare."'";
            $noOfEvent= mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($dbconnection, $sqlCount));
            if($noOfEvent > 0){
                $result['classList'][] = 'event';
            }
        }
        $result['content'] = "<a href='".$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']."?month=".$dateOfCell->format('m')."&day=".$dateOfCell->format('d')."&year=".$datOfCell->format('Y')."&v=true'>".$cellNo."</a>";
    }
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
    <head> 
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // Fixing some strange behavior of javascript date math (31. March - one Month => 03. March)
            // read more here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41840767/5200357
            Date.prototype.getNextMonth = function() {
                var result = new Date(this),
                    expectedMonth = ((this.getMonth() + 1) % 12 + 12) % 12;
                result.setMonth(result.getMonth() + 1);
                if (result.getMonth() !== expectedMonth) {
                    result.setDate(0);
                }
                return result;
            }
            Date.prototype.getPreviousMonth = function() {
                var result = new Date(this),
                    expectedMonth = ((this.getMonth() - 1 + 12) % 12 + 12) % 12;
                result.setMonth(result.getMonth() - 1);
                if (result.getMonth() !== expectedMonth) {
                    result.setDate(0);
                }
                return result;
            }
            //This function represents the previous button on the calender
            var actualDate = new Date('2017-09-01');
            function goPreviousMonth(){
                // Sub one month
                actualDate = actualDate.getPreviousMonth();
                //This creates the URL to state the month and year.
                document.location.href = "<?=$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];?>?month="+actualDate.getMonth()+"&year="+actualDate.getFullYear(); 
            }
            //This function represents the next button on the calender
            function goNextMonth() {
                // Add one month
                actualDate = actualDate.getNextMonth();
                //This creates the URL to state the month and year.
                document.location.href = "<?=$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];?>?month="+monthstring+"&year="+year; 
            }
        </script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="calenderstyle.css">
    </head>
    <body>
<?php
    if(array_key_exists('add', $_GET))
        if($successFullInsertedEvent){
            echo "Event was successfully added";
        } else {
            echo "Event was not added";
        }
    }
?>
        <table border='1'> 
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input class="previousbutton" type='button' value='<' name='previousbutton' onClick="goPreviousMonth()">
                    </td> 
                    <td colspan='5'>
                        <span class="title"><?=$monthName." ".$year?></span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input class="nextbutton" type='button' value='>' name='nextbutton' onClick="goNextMonth()">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Sun</td>
                    <td>Mon</td>
                    <td>Tue</td>
                    <td>Wed</td>
                    <td>Thu</td>
                    <td>Fri</td>
                    <td>Sat</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
<?php   for($cellNo = 0; $cellNo < ceil(($numDays+$firstDayOfCurrentMonth)/7)*7; $cellNo++): ?>
<?php       if($cellNo % 7 == 0 && $cellNo > 0): ?>
                </tr>
                <tr>
<?php       endif;
            $cellInformation = getContentsOfCell($cellNo, $currentDate);
?>
                    <td class="<?=implode(', ', $cellInformation['classList'])?>" <?=implode(' ', $cellInformation['attributes'])?>><?=$cellInformation['content']?></td>
<?php   endfor; ?>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
<?php
    // This should also placed at the top but I left it for practise ;)
    if(isset($_GET['v'])){
        echo "<a href='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?month=".$month."&day=".$day."&year=".$year."&v=true&f=true'>Add Event</a>";
        if(isset($_GET['f'])){
            include("eventform.php");
        }
        $sqlEvent="select * from booking where event_date='".$month."/".$day."/".$year."'";
        $resultEvents=mysqli_query($dbconnection,$sqlEvent);
        echo "<hr>";
        while($events=mysqli_fetch_array($resultEvents)){
            echo "Title : ".$events['title']."<br>"; 
            echo "Detail : ".$events['detail']."<br>";
        }
    }
?>
    </body>
</html>
```

This code is **untested**. I don't have your sql database structure, data and stuff. It should lead you in the right direction and is not meant as a fully working piece of code! Please keep this in mind.

Comment: If you have any questions or problems, please feel free to ask. I'm sure there are a few errors in the code because it's all written without any testing! So if you can fix it by yourself that's fine. But if you have any problems that you cannot solve by yourself leave a comment and I will try to help you.

Comment: Thank you so much for your generous help. Of course, if I have any other questions or need any help, I will leave you a comment. Thank you again for everything.