# Javascript - How to subtract months from Firebase Firestore Timestamp?

Tags: javascript, firebase, timestamp, google-cloud-firestore

How to subtract date from `admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()`?

Let's say I want to know the date 5 months ago.

By using the `new Date()` Javascript object, I get the date in  milliseconds.

I would like to save it though as a timestamp in my Firestore Database. How can I accomplish that?

**UPDATE**:

I use this function to discover the date:

```
function findBirthdate(age){
    var monthsAgo; 
    switch(age){
       case "_6months":
           monthsAgo = 3;
           break;
       case "6_12months":
           monthsAgo = 9;
           break;
       case "12_18months":
           monthsAgo = 15;
           break;
       case "18_24months":
           monthsAgo = 21;
           break;
       case "24_months":
           monthsAgo = 28;
           break;
       default:
           return;
   }

   var now = new Date();
   return now.setMonth(now.getMonth() - monthsAgo);
}
```

So, I call `var birth = findBirthdate(age)` and send `birth` to Firestore as in

`admin.firestore()....update({ birthdate: birth }).then(...`

Comment: Since Firestore just stores the `Date` value you pass in, this should be as simple as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7937233/how-do-i-calculate-the-date-in-javascript-three-months-prior-to-today

Comment: Puf, it happens though that when I save the `serverTimestamp` it is pretty beautiful in the Firestore console (such that I can change days, months, etc through a mini calendar and the data is said to be of type timestamp). When I do through the method you suggested (and that I talked about in my question as using the standard `Date` object, I rather get a `1508193230712` as a Date, which I could use as well in my client code with no problems. It is not nice though for manipulation in the Firebase console. Any suggestions then?

Comment: Please show the code of how you save the "5 months ago" in the database. As long as you write it as a `Date` object it should work, but we might be missing something.

Comment: Puff, updated the code

Comment: That looks fine, but doesn't set anything in the database yet. If you don't get them as a date in the database, that's the only thing I can think of. Note that it'd be really helpful to have a [minimal complete repro for this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), because it's inefficient to interactively debug the problem with Stack Overflow in the middle.

Comment: Puff, just tested and `now` prints as a normal Date while the result of the operation `now.setMonth(now.getMonth() - monthsAgo)`, whatever the value of `monthsAgo` is, is printing the number of milliseconds instead. How to solve it then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I do

```
var date = new Date(); 
date.setMonth(date.getMonth() - 3); 
console.log(date);
```

It prints

> Tue Apr 17 2018 21:11:19 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)

The difference is that you return the result from `setMonth`, which happens to be the resulting timestamp. From the [MDN documentation on `setMonth()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setMonth):

> Returns: The number of milliseconds between 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC and the updated date.

Since you want to return the actual date, you'll need to do:

```
var now = new Date();
now.setMonth(now.getMonth() - monthsAgo);
return now;
```