# How to limit the maximum date in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a datetime-local to select dates in the calendar, what I want is that from the current date, only a maximum of three months can be selected.For now what I have tried does not work, if someone could help me.

```
 const currentDate = new Date();
 const restrictionMonths = currentDate.getMonth() +2;

   <div className="relative">
      <label className="block mb-2 text-xs font-medium text-stone-600">Fecha baja</label>
      <Field type="datetime-local" min={new Date().toISOString().slice(0, -8)}  max={restrictionMonths} name="publishEndDate" className="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-teal-500 focus:border-teal-500 block w-full p-2.5" placeholder="Seleccionar fecha"/>
      <ErrorMessage name="publishEndDate" component="span" className="mt-2 text-xs text-red-600"/>
   </div>
```

Comment: You need to include the library that you are using for Field. You don't have a setter or state variable to track the state

Comment: I am using formik to upload the form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
<input
    type="datetime-local"
    min={new Date().toISOString().slice(0, -8)}
    max={new Date(new Date().setMonth(new Date().getMonth() + 3)).toISOString().slice(0, -8)}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
const restrictionMonths = () => {
 return currentDate.setMonth(currentDate.getMonth() + 3);
}
```

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7937233/how-do-i-calculate-the-date-in-javascript-three-months-prior-to-today) is other ways to change month